# Gradle won't allow multiple includeBuild statements with the same endpoint name in their paths

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, include

I'm trying to include modules from my own library in `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = "MyApp"
include ':app'

includeBuild '/usr/local/library/Android/Event/code'
includeBuild '/usr/local/library/Android/Location/code'
includeBuild '/usr/local/library/Android/Widget/code'
```

But gradle complains:

> Included build /usr/local/library/Android/Event/code has build path :code which is the same as included build /usr/local/library/Android/Location/code

I'd really like to keep all Android/gradle related files in `code` for each library module, instead of one level up, e.g.:

`/usr/local/library/Android/Event`

... or one level down, e.g.:

`/usr/local/library/Android/Event/code/event`

Is there any way to achieve this? Perhaps by specifying a different build path or alias (or something to that effect) for each `includeBuild` directive?